# Nonsense results in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting some nonsense results when I run 4 different queries.

The main one is:

```
SELECT distinct p.id 
FROM praxis px,basis_medikation bm,therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm,therapie_zyklus tz,therapie t,patient p, behandlung b 
WHERE 1=1 
AND EXISTS (select * from diagnose d, diagnose_mamma dm, tumor_status ts where d.patient_id = p.id and d.diagnose_mamma_id = dm.id and d.deleted = 0  
   and ts.tumorstatus_m in ('M1') 
   and d.datum < t.datum 
   and (ts.id = dm.tumorstatus_id or ts.id = dm.tumorstatus_rechts_id)) 
 AND px.ID = p.praxis_ID AND px.testpraxis = 0 AND tz.deleted = 0  and tzm.deleted = 0 and t.deleted = 0 AND p.ID = t.patient_ID AND t.ID = tz.therapie_id AND tz.ID = tzm.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm.basis_medikation_id = bm.ID 
 AND t.datum >= to_date('2009-10-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND t.datum < to_date('2013-10-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
 AND t.behandlung_id = b.id
 AND b.deleted = 0
 AND ( 
       ( 
        bm.atcaname in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4')  
        AND bm.product_name <> 'Medizin0'  
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       ) 
       OR ( 
        bm.atcaname in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4')  
        AND bm.product_name <> 'Medizin0' 
        AND EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       ) 
       OR ( 
        bm.atcaname in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4')  
        AND bm.product_name <> 'Medizin0'  
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       ) 
       OR ( 
        bm.atcaname not in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4') 
        AND bm.product_name = 'Medizin0'  
        AND EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       )
       OR ( 
        bm.atcaname not in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4') 
        AND bm.product_name = 'Medizin0'  
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       ) 
       OR ( 
        bm.atcaname not in ('Medizin1','Medizin2','Medizin3','Medizin4') 
        AND bm.product_name = 'Medizin0'  
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin5') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from basis_medikation bm2, therapie_zyklus_medikation tzm2, therapie_zyklus tz2 where tz2.therapie_id = tz.therapie_id AND tz2.ID = tzm2.therapiezyklus_id AND tzm2.basis_medikation_id = bm2.ID and bm2.atcaname = 'Medizin6') 
       ) 
      ) ;
```

It selects patients with breast cancer that had been treated either with Medizin1 or Medizin2 or Medizin3 or Medizin4 only, and those who had combined any of those medicines with Medizin5 or Medizin6, and those who had been treated with Medizin0 and Medizin5, and those who had been treated with Medizin0 and Medizin6 and those who had been treated only with Medizin0...

For the second query I only add the condition

```
AND b.line = 1
```

For the third query I add:

```
AND b.line = 2
```

And for the fourth:

```
AND b.line > 2
```

And the nonsense comes when the number of results for the first query is lower than the sum of the results of the other three queries... that should be equal or less... I think..

But indeed I am missing something...

Comment: Every time you are writing a single SQL query and it doesn't fit on one screen anymore, you should stop and think if you can't solve the problem in a more elegant way.

Comment: Did you check if some of the returned rows are duplicates? Do a UNION of all three queries to find out.

Comment: It's really hard to guess at what the solution could be to this problem without actually seeing the data in your database.  I would take a close look at your data to make sure that `b.line` has the values you are expecting.

Comment: Any suggestions Philipp?

Comment: willOEM the values are either 1, 2, or greater than 2... there are some null and some lower than 1 but it doesn't make sense either with those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the nonsense comes when the number of results for the first query
>   is lower than the sum of the results of the other three queries...
>   that should be equal or less... I think..

I think your logic is flawed, but it does depend on your data.

If you have the same `patient.id` with a record where `behandlung.line` is 1, and one where it is 2, and one where it is 3, then the ID will be listed exactly once by all four of your queries (because of the `distinct`). That doesn't mean it's wrong, but the sum of the counts of the filtered queries will be 3, while the unfiltered query will still only have one row.

`count(distinct id)` is not the same as `count (id)`, and not comparable to:

```
count(distinct case when line = 1 then id end)
  + count(distinct case when line = 2 then id end)
  + count(distinct case when line > 2 then id end)
```

Without the `distinct` your logic would apply, though the `exists` sill complicates it a little.

Maybe an example will help, simplified to ignore all the joins etc.:

```
create table t42 (id number, line number);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (1, 1);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (1, 2);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (2, 1);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (2, 2);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (2, 3);
insert into t42 (id, line) values (3, 2);
```

Your first query finds 3 rows:

```
select distinct id from t42;

        ID
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 

 3 rows selected
```

You second query finds two rows, but both of the IDs are (of course) included in the first query result too:

```
select distinct id from t42 where line = 1;

        ID
----------
         1 
         2 

 2 rows selected
```

The third query finds three rows, this time entirely duplicating the result set from the first query (in this very contrived case), *and* those from the second query:

```
select distinct id from t42 where line = 2;

        ID
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 

 3 rows selected
```

And your third query only finds one row, which is in all the previous result sets:

```
select distinct id from t42 where line > 2;

        ID
----------
         2 

 1 rows selected
```

So the first query finds three rows, which is fewer than the sum of the rows found by the other three - 2 + 3 + 1 is six. All of the result sets are correct, but you can't compare the total number of rows, because the same IDs are being included in multiple sets. ID `1` is counted twice, `2` is counted three times, and `3` is counted once.

The total number of IDs in the result sets is the same - it's the same three IDS after all - 
and no IDs magically appear in the three filtered queries that weren't present in the original unfiltered one. But you'd have to eliminate duplicates to make any kind of comparison. Unioning the three filtered queries and counting the number of remaining distinct IDs across all three would match the original query, for example. (In this case; you said you had rows with `line < 1`, so in your real query the total would be lower as you expected).

Comment: Thanks :) I was too obstinate with this one, and it was not that difficult!